# Yahoo mail always sending 250 code for SMTP rcpt

Tags: email, smtp

As the title suggest yahoo.com gives back a 250 codefor good and bad e-mail addresses, i.e for one's that exist and those that don't.

Is this just Yahoo policy or am I doing something wrong?

If it is their policy is there any programmatic way to confirm if a Yahoo address is real or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo gives 250 code only when the email is valid 
For invalid emails you will get 554 code.

Yahoo.com works as a **catch all** email system
A catch-all account is an email address that collects all the mail sent to your domain name not sent to the other email addresses known to the server.
https://www.corporatecomm.com/faqs/other-questions/what-is-a-catch-all-account

So you can't verify a yahoo email [unlike gmail] through stream socket connection, you have to send the email and receive the bounce response, or you can use an email verifying service.

Comment: I'm making a direct stream connection in PHP with basic SMTP, i.e just the HELO call. No matter what e-mail address I use for Yahoo it returns 250, other providers give 550 as expected for a non-existent e-mail address.

Comment: @Appalling, yahoo.com is a catch all domain, so you can't verify it without sending actual email.

Comment: Ok well that would explain it.